# How to change statusbar color when used alongside InAppBrowser plugin in iOS?

Tags: ios, cordova, statusbar, inappbrowser

I'm trying to change InAppBrowser statusbar color which by default light content using cordova-plugin-statusbar but will always remain white. How can I change it to other color? I tried using StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString and StatusBar.styleBlackOpaque but none worked...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to update InAppBrowser plugin myself, on CDVInAppBrowser.m, I have added this line

```
self.addressLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:1.0];
```

This changes StatusBar color even inside InAppBrowser which isn't altered by using StatusBar plugin flags.